# Spring webflux convert flux to DTO after grouping certain fields into a child DTO object

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

My rest api is using Spring Webflux. While fetching an Entity from Postgres which is denormalized table, I am getting multiple rows for the same object. While converting to DTO, I need to iterate through multiple User objects for the same user and make a list of all departments he/she is part of and then add the list to the DTO. This way, I can send back a single row per User. How can I achieve this without blocking.

```
@Entity
public Class User {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String department;
    private String departmentArea;

}

public Class UserDTO {
    
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<DepartmentDTO> departmentDTO;
    
}
```

How to I convert the User objects into a UserDTO with a list of DepartmentDTO

Current implementation in service

```
userRepo.findAllUsersByIds().map(mapper::mapUserDTO));
```

Comment: Does it mean `findAllUsersByIds` returns `Flux<User>`?

Comment: Yes. I will get a flux of users with multiple rows for the same user with multiple departments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupBy` operator to group by `id` and then map every group into a `UserDTO`

```
Flux<UserDTO> res = userRepo.findAllUsersByIds()
        .groupBy(user -> user.getId())
        .flatMap(group ->
                group.collectList()
                        .map(users -> {
                            var userDto = new UserDTO();
                            userDto.setId(group.key());
                            userDto.setName(users.get(0).getName());
                            userDto.setDepartmentDTO(
                                    users.stream()
                                            .map(user -> {
                                                var deptDto = new DepartmentDTO();
                                                deptDto.setName(user.getDepartment());
                                                deptDto.setArea(user.getDepartmentArea());
                                                return deptDto;
                                            })
                                            .toList()
                            );
                            return userDto;
                        })
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a native English speaker. So sorry for my bad English.

I think you can use `groupBy` on the `Flux`.
`groupBy` needs a keyMapper. In your case, it would be a user's `id` and `name`.

```
userRepo.findAllUsersByIds()
.groupBy(user -> new UserDto(user.getId(), user.getName()))
```

After grouping the `Flux`, there are `GroupedFlux` in your stream.
`GroupedFlux` has a key and value. Key is the value passed through keyMapper above.
`GroupedFlux` itself are the values grouped by key. So `GroupedFlux.collectList()` would return `List<User>`.

```
.flatMap(groupedFlux -> 
    Mono.zip(
        groupedFlux.key(),
        groupedFlux.collectList()
    )
)
```

The value passed through `flatMap` is a tuple that has `UserDto` and `List<User>`.
So cast it into `UserDto` that you want to respond.

```
.flatMap(tuple -> {
    // tuple.getT2() would be the grouped user list. (List<User>)
    // cast it into List<DepartmentDTO>
    // ...
    tuple.t1.setDepartmentDto(...);

    // return UserDto
    return Mono.just(
        tuple.t1
    );
})
```

The overall code would be like

```
userRepo.findAllUsersByIds()
.groupBy(user -> new UserDto(user.getId(), user.getName()))
.flatMap(groupedFlux -> 
    Mono.zip(
        groupedFlux.key(),
        groupedFlux.collectList()
    )
)
.flatMap(tuple -> {
    // tuple.getT2() would be the grouped user list. (List<User>)
    // cast it into List<DepartmentDTO>
    // ...
    tuple.t1.setDepartmentDto(...);

    // return UserDto
    return Mono.just(
        tuple.t1
    );
})
```